# Error handling in spring integration

Tags: error-handling, spring-integration

I have three different systems. I am using Spring integration to sync data in all these system.

System 1 calls --- > System 2 via http:inbound gateway

```
<int-http:inbound-gateway id="gateway"
    path="/save" supported-methods="POST, PUT"
    request-channel="requestChannel" reply-channel="replyChannel"
    request-payload-type="com.model.Request"
    mapped-request-headers="source" error-channel="errorChannel" />
```

System 2 will call service method to persist data which returns response if request is valid else throws exception

```
<int:service-activator ref="serviceMethod"
    method="saveIfValid" input-channel="requestChannel"
    output-channel="serviceOutput" />

<int:recipient-list-router id="id1"
    input-channel="serviceOutput">
    <int:recipient channel="system1" />
    <int:recipient channel="system3" />
</int:recipient-list-router>
```

I need to send service method response to system 1 and system 3 only if operation is successful.
 After calling service method, based on service method response, request for system 3 will be generated using transformer. After transformer I am putting request in mq queue.

```
<int:transformer id="transformer1"
    method="convert" input-channel="system3"
    output-channel="jmsInput">
    <bean
        class="com.transformer.System3Transformer" />
</int:transformer> 


<int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter id="adapter"
    channel="jmsInput" destination-name="queueName">
</int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter>
```

Updated JMS outbound code

```html
<int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter id="jms1"
  channel="jmsIn" destination-name="queueName">
  <int-jms:request-handler-advice-chain>
   <bean
    class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice">
     <property name="onSuccessExpression" value="T(Boolean).TRUE" />
    <property name="successChannelName" value="afterSuccessDeleteChannel" />
       <property name="onFailureExpression" value="T(Boolean).FALSE" />
    <property name="failureChannelName" value="afterFailRenameChannel" />
   </bean>
  </int-jms:request-handler-advice-chain>
 </int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter>
```

My question is

- if service class fails I need to send error response and stop the flow
- if service method successful persisted data, but transformation fails, system 1 should get success response and error should be logged.
- Here as I am using error channel in outbound adapter, even if error occurs in transformer it is returned to system 1.
- please suggest how can i  handle error without using global error channel and how to handle error in jms outbound adapter.

  - thank you for answering my quesion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first case you should really just rely on the exception propagation - the flow stops and error is sent to the system1 as an HTTP response.

For the second (`transformer`) case you should take a look into the `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` and use it with the `<request-handler-advice-chain>` for the `<transformer>`.

The same can be applied for the `<int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter>`, if you should acknowledge to the system1.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#expression-advice

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/intermediate/retry-and-more

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. if any error happens in <int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter> i just want it log , I do not want to show error to system 1. can you please help to implement this also ?

Comment: `<int-jms:request-handler-advice-chain>
                                   <bean
 class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice">
    <property name="onSuccessExpression" value="payload" /> 
    <property name="successChannelName" value="afterSuccessDeleteChannel" />
    <property name="onFailureExpression" value="payload" /> 
    <property name="failureChannelName" value="afterFailRenameChannel" />
   </bean>`

Comment: Please see above code. It going to both success channel and failure channel. Can you please explain how it evaluates whether it is succeed or failed? .

Comment: As you see the code snippet isn't readable from the comments. You can always edit your question with the proper formatting. If you want only log, you can subscribe `<logging-channel-adapter>` to the `failureChannel` of that advice. If you don't want to send error back, there is a `trapException` option. Please, read `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` JavaDocs and mentioned Reference Manual for understanding how it works.

Comment: Hi I have updated my question with code snippet for jms outbound adapter. Can you please take a look. It is redirecting to both success and failure channel and throwing org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice$MessageHandlingExpressionEvaluatingAdviceException: Handler Failed. org.springframework.messaging.core.DestinationResolutionException: no output-channel or replyChannel header available

Comment: That says your downstream flow is based on some request-reply component, but it is one-way route by nature. Consider to `nullChannel` if you are not interested in the reply. To be honest, it is already different story. The answer to this question is about `ExpressionEva‌luatingRequestHandle‌​rAdvice` and that's all.